# Multiple Custom Post Type queries, how to DRY it up

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

I need to be able to display the latest post from 4 different custom post types and then use those posts inside a carousel. Everything is working fine but I'm not happy with how my code looks as I'm repeating everything.

First I made 4 different Queries for the different custom post types:

```
<!--recipes -->
<?php
$recipesQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'recipes',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
?>

<!--value -->
<?php
$valueQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'value_chain',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
?>

<!--press-->
<?php
$pressQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'press',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
?>

<!--multimedia -->
<?php
$mediaQuery = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => 'multimedia',
        'posts_per_page' => 1
) );
?>
```

And then I repeat this code block 4 times, one for each post type:

```
<?php if ( $valueQuery->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $valueQuery->have_posts() ) : $valueQuery->the_post(); ?>  
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
                    <?php if( $thumb ):?>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 back">
                            <div class="back"
                                <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
                                style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>');">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="info">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="excerpt"><p></p></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read-more">
                                            <?php echo _e('Leer más', 'myCustomTemplate'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-bg">
                            <div class="info">
                                <h3>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                        <?php the_title(); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </h3>
                                <hr>
                                <div class="excerpt"><p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 100 ); ?></p></div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read-more">
                                            <?php echo _e('Leer más', 'myCustomTemplate'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Is there a better way to do this? I am aware I can create an array with the Custom post types but not sure how I could use it to create the carousel items.

Comment: What about wrapping it into a function with the post type as an input argument? Then there is e.g. get_template_part().

Comment: Or just a loop...

Comment: If you can show me the loop example I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below example is your code in a loop. The `post_types` array includes all the post types that you're querying. Then, the next bit (`foreach`, more info [here](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)) runs the code wrapped in curly braces (`{` to `}`) for each item in that `post_types`-array.

```
post_types = array('recipes', 'value_chain', 'press', 'multimedia');

foreach($post_types as $post_type){

    $query = new WP_Query ( array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => 1
    ) );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>  
            <div class="item">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
                        <?php if( $thumb ):?>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 back">
                                <div class="back"
                                    <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
                                    style="background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>');">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h3>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="excerpt"><p></p></div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read-more">
                                                <?php echo _e('Leer más', 'myCustomTemplate'); ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 no-bg">
                                <div class="info">
                                    <h3>
                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                            <?php the_title(); ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h3>
                                    <hr>
                                    <div class="excerpt"><p><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 100 ); ?></p></div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="read-more">
                                                <?php echo _e('Leer más', 'myCustomTemplate'); ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile;
    endif; wp_reset_postdata(); 

}
?>
```